# More Efficient way to zoom background image

Tags: javascript, animation, frontend, motion

My current code for enlarging the background-image is as follows.

```
.portfolioItem {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 25vw; 

    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;

    position: relative;

    transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

.portfolioItem:hover {
    background-size: 110% 110%;
}
```

I've attempted to streamline it as much as possible but it still lags very heavily.

Is there another method of performing this action with less lag/higher performance?  I'm open to JS solutions but CSS definitely seems like the best tool for the job in my mind.

Comment: What exactly is "lagging"? This should work fine, unless your browser has a problem with graphics anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `css transform`or `css3 transform` or `animation`   just like this

```
.portfolioItem:hover{
-webkit-animation:ex 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ex{
   0%{transform:scale(1,1);}
   100%{transform:scale(2,2);}
}
```